# How can I show more text on div hover?

Tags: css, hover

I'm working on a website to show some more text on hover. Here is a live snippet:

```css
#democontent {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 3%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
}
#imagecontent {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.7% 2%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#imagecontent:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
}
#contentimage {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
  width: 19%;
}
```

```html
<div id="democontent">
  <div id="contentimage">
    <img src="" />
  </div>

  <div id="imagecontent">
    <ul class="bullet">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</li>
      <li>Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue</li>
      <li>mper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per</li>
      <li>er inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.</li>
      <li>Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue</li>
      <li>mper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per</li>
      <li>er inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor.</li>


    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have an image and I want to orient the `div` side to side. If I hover over the `div` that has the content, it overlaps the image. Any idea how I can do that without the `div` overlapping the image?

Comment: Increase the image size and name it img2. When you hover the div, replace the img1 in src with img2 . That will do the trick .

Comment: will try..but how does that effect the overlap ?

Comment: Don't add `position: absolute` on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/sGDvj/665/

Comment: yeah..if i dont position absolute, the divs height is increased onhover..i tried that..

Comment: @Vidia When you hover, the image will be replaced with a bigger image and the hovered content , which is much larger then actual content comes inside that image, so no overlapping.

Comment: @Vidia isn't that what you wanted - how show the extra text without covering the image?

Comment: @Vidia user davidpauljunior gave you a solution for what you asked in OP. Now, you mention something with div height. If you can reform your question, perhaps any users will be able to help you more precisely. isn't it?

Comment: Please look at the following demo, I think it is what you want ..

http://jsfiddle.net/sGDvj/666/

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  <style type="text/css">
    #democontent {
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding: 3%;
        width: 80%;
        height:150px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #imagecontent {
        background-color: #E3E3E3;
        border-radius: 12px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.7% 2%;
        width: 400px;
        height:150px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;

    }

    #imagecontent:hover{
        width: 400px;
        height:auto;
    }
    #contentimage {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 1% 0 0;
        width: 19%;
    }
    </style>
```